# Probability mass function and Random measure

Tags: random-variable, dirichlet-process, measure-theory

I have seen this in a few tutorial and papers on `Dirichlet Process`, where people refer to the probability mass function of [stick-breaking-process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#The_stick-breaking_process) as a `random measure`. From the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure) there doesn't seem to be any link between these two. I wonder what is the relationship.

**Note:** [I am a computer science student, so there are definitely some missing stuff in my knowledge which may seem obvious to a statistics student].

Comment: You were one Wikipedia click away from the connection! From the page on "random element" (linked on the page for "random measure"): "In probability theory, random element is a generalization of the concept of random variable to more complicated spaces than the simple real line".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirichlet process can be thought of as a random variable where any particular realisation is a measure. In the case of the Dirichlet process this random measure is almost surely a discrete probability measure, and may be written as
$$
\sum_i w_i \delta_{X_i},
$$
where $\{w_i\}$ are distributed according to a stick breaking process and the atom locations $X_i$ are i.i.d from some distribution.